# Take advantage of caching in the browser

Tags: c#, azure, cloudflare

It is such that I have taken a test on Google Page Speed insights and describing the more time that I need to looked at my "Take advantage of caching in the browser" on page

I have azure and set CloudFlare SSL on all https page.

Is there some code or other as do you in some way help since anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using CloudFlare, there's an easy way to specify settings for browser caching. From the CloudFlare admin panel go to Domain > CloudFlare Settings > Performance Settings > Minimum TTL. I generally set this to 1 month.

FWIW, personally I find www.webpagetest.org gives better feedback for refinements like this, it gives more detailed feedback of caching details for each individual resource.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll get right back if it does not work, but I hope it works,